# How can we print the variable name along with its value in python, which will be useful during debugging?

Tags: python, inspection

I have written something like this multiple times:

```
print 'customer id: ', customerId
```

I want to have a function which prints variable name along with the value

```
>>myprint(customerId)

>>customerId: 12345
```

Comment: @Kasra he has many variables he dosen't want to do the same typing instead want to call a function

Comment: What if `12345` is referenced by more than one name? Or none (e.g. only referenced via a list)? Read this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `test_str = 'hello'; myprint(test_str);` what will happen ? the `TrueValue` of the variable `test_str`, which is `"hello"` , will be passed to the function `myprint`, not along with the `VariableName`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thats what I am talking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing exactly what you require involves a O(n) lookup in the symbol table, which is terrible IMHO.

If you can pass the string corresponding to the variable name, you can do this:

```
import sys

def myprint(name, mod=sys.modules[__name__]):
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, getattr(mod, name)))
```

Test:

```
a=535
b='foo'
c=3.3

myprint('a')
myprint('b')
myprint('c')
```

Will print:

```
a: 535
b: foo
c: 3.3
```

You can use it also for printing variables from another module by passing the second argument, e.g.:

```
>>> import os
>>> myprint('pathsep', os)
pathsep: :
```

Comment: This does *not* answer the OP's question.

Comment: Is lookup table not a hash? In that case, this should work in O(1) time.

Comment: The code to do it would be `for k, v in globals().items(): if v is a: return k`, which is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to hand-type the variable name into your helper function's argument every time you call it, which makes it the same as directly formatting the strings into a printed message.

Another possible (useless?) heck can be the following:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("__(.+)")
def check_value(checkpoint_name):
    print "============"
    print checkpoint_name
    print "============"
    for variable_name, variable_value in globals().items():
        if regex.match(variable_name) is None:
            print "%s\t:\t%s" % (variable_name, str(variable_value))
    print "============"
```

,which prints all non-system-protected, declared variables in global scope per call. To call the function, do

```
 a = 0
 check_value("checkpoint after definition of a")

 b = 1
 check_value("checkpoint after definition of b")
```

Feel free to customize the function for your need. I just came up with this, not sure if this works the way you want...